# how to obtain a reference to the lite plugin object for ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Beginning web developer here, bear with me, I realize this question is simplistic.

I am trying to use the LITE plugin for ckeditor. In the documentation (http://www.loopindex.com/lite/docs/) they say that in order to get a reference to the lite plugin object I need to

"To interact with the lite plugin, you need to obtain a reference to the actual plugin object which is unique for each instance of CKEditor. The safest way to do this is by listening to the event LITE.Events.INIT fired by the editor instance. The data member of the event will contain a property called lite which references the lite plugin instance, initialized and ready for action."

How do I do this?

Is it something like:

```
LITE.Events.INIT(data) {
   //desired functionality here
}
```

or is it:

```
LITE.Events.INIT.addEventListener (function (data) {//desired functionality here})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without having access to the plugin, but according to the documentation this should work:

```
editor.on( LITE.Events.INIT, function( evt ) {
    // The instance should be somewhere in:
    evt.data;
} );
```

Note that `LITE.Events.INIT` is a constant which keeps the name of Lite's event name. It's not a name of the event.